# Jquery validationEngine fadeDuration option when hiding prompt

Tags: jquery, hide, fade, jquery-validation-engine

I'm using validationEngine for validation of an HTML form. There is a place where I need to hide a specific prompt when a button is clicked. The function in question:

```
jQuery('#target').validationEngine('hide', {fadeDuration: 0.9});
```

The specific prompt hides correctly, but does not fade out. It simply disappears without delay. The function in the jquery.validationEngine.js is as follow:

```
/**
    * Closes form error prompts, CAN be invidual
    */
    hide: function() {
         var form = $(this).closest('form');
         var options = form.data('jqv');
         var fadeDuration = (options && options.fadeDuration) ? options.fadeDuration : 0.3;
         var closingtag;

         //alert(fadeDuration);

         if($(this).is("form")) {
             closingtag = "parentForm"+methods._getClassName($(this).attr("id"));
         } else {
             closingtag = methods._getClassName($(this).attr("id")) +"formError";
         }
         $('.'+closingtag).fadeTo(fadeDuration, 0.3, function() {
             $(this).parent('.formErrorOuter').remove();
             $(this).remove();
         });
         return this;
     },
```

When I insert the line alert(fadeDuration); it shows 0.3. Obviously the value of fadeDuration is not declared correctly on my side, but how can I make it right?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this but, it doesn't make a huge difference on the fadeout. Apparently hide doesn't accept an options parameter (looking at the source code) but, you can change the fadeDuration on the whole form by doing the following:

```
$('#field').closest('form, .validationEngineContainer').data('jqv').fadeDuration = .99;
```